# Unable to flash firmware

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I tried to flash Samsung Galaxy note 2 Gt-N7100 firmware *N7100XXUFNL1_N7100ODDFNI1_N7100DDUFND1_HOME.tar.md* 5 using odin version 1.85 ,3.07 , 3.09 , 3.12 .3 but i am getting Fail as odin status i found that i need to flash pit file so , i flashed pit *PIT_N7100_16GB_20121102.pit* along with it but still getting status as Fail .Then i tried flashing twrp too but still status is fail

**Odin log**

```
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/005> Odin engine v(ID:3.1203)..
<ID:0/005> File analysis..
<ID:0/005> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/005> Initialzation..
<ID:0/005> Set PIT file..
<ID:0/005> DO NOT TURN OFF TARGET!!
<ID:0/005> FAIL!
<ID:0/005> 
<ID:0/005> Re-Partition operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
<ID:0/005> Removed!!
<ID:0/005> Added!!
```

I have TWRP recovery installed but i am unable to mount .
Internal storage , External sd card ,OTG are showing 0mb.When i boot into twrp a to3g window opens in to my laptop.
Please help me fix this.

**Odin log With Repartition unticked**

```
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> N7100XXUFNL1_N7100ODDFNI1_N7100DDUFND1_HOME.tar.md5 is valid.
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 0)
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 0)
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 0)
<ID:0/004> Added!!
<ID:0/004> Odin v.3 engine (ID:4)..
<ID:0/004> File analysis..
<ID:0/004> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/004> Initialzation..
<ID:0/004> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/004> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/004> sboot.bin
<ID:0/004> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/004> FAIL!
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
<ID:0/004> Removed!!
<ID:0/004> Added!!
<ID:0/004> Removed!!
<ID:0/004> Added!!
<ID:0/004> Removed!!
<ID:0/004> Added!!
<ID:0/004> Removed!!
<ID:0/004> Added!!
<ID:0/004> Removed!!
<ID:0/004> Added!!
<ID:0/004> Removed!!
<ID:0/004> Added!!
<ID:0/004> Removed!!
<ID:0/004> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> N7100XXUFNL1_N7100ODDFNI1_N7100DDUFND1_HOME.tar.md5 is valid.
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/004> Odin v.3 engine (ID:4)..
<ID:0/004> File analysis..
<ID:0/004> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/004> Initialzation..
<ID:0/004> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/004> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/004> sboot.bin
<ID:0/004> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/004> FAIL!
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
<ID:0/004> Removed!!
<ID:0/004> Added!!
<ID:0/004> Odin v.3 engine (ID:4)..
<ID:0/004> File analysis..
<ID:0/004> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/004> Initialzation..
<ID:0/004> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/004> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/004> sboot.bin
<ID:0/004> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/004> FAIL!
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

Comment: what device is this? very difficult to help without more info

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note 2 GT-N7100.

Comment: Does flashing without PIT return errors?

Comment: Yes same errors

Comment: Is there any solution?Can you please share this topic with others?

Comment: @esQmo could you please help by sharing this post?

Comment: @MarkYisri Samsung Galaxy Note 2 GT-N7100 .

Comment: @samy untick the Repartition option and send the log

Comment: @esQmo ok i already did that but still same failed status let me retry and post log.

Comment: @esQmo see the log i updated in this post right now.

Comment: This seems like an hardware issue. The eMMC can't be written. You need to flash through JTAG interface instead of USB.

Comment: @esQmo I'm new to this can  you please tell how to flash through JTAG?

Comment: Or prior to JTAG, try flashing the boot partition, may be only the boot is damaged. Google for it then flash using Odin

Comment: @esQmo i cant find anything about flashing  boot partition can you please help me.

Comment: head here: http://www.unlockforum.com/showthread.php/sd-boot-recovery-files-i9300-n7100-n8000-i9500-10656p2.html